# Do we have org.openrewrite.build.recipe-library plugin available for maven project

Tags: openrewrite

Below are the plugins available for Gradle project. Do we have same plugin if I want to opt Maven project instead of Gradle:-

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.openrewrite.rewrite") version("6.1.8") // available in maven
    id("org.openrewrite.build.recipe-library") version "latest.release" // not found in maven
}
```

If not adding last plugin then getting below error in maven project:-

```
[INFO] Validating active recipes...
[ERROR] Recipe validation error in com.sk.app.MyMergeYamlRecipe: Unable to load Recipe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sk.app.MyMergeYamlRecipe` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific plugin provided for folks that want to develop recipes in an Apache Maven project. That said, there are folks out there using Apache Maven to develop and share their recipes, such as for instance the Axon Framework: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/migration/pom.xml
Feel free to see what you can learn from their approach, and let us know if you run into any limitations.

Comment: what is the use of this plugin org.openrewrite.build.recipe-library if I am developing custom recipe by using Rewrite API? Can I run and develop my custom recipe in local without using this plugin? I am trying to customize MergeYaml recipe, so I can apply change only to specified YAML file.

Comment: The Gradle plugin adds a number of conventions as seen here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-build-gradle-plugin/blob/main/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/gradle/RewriteRecipeLibraryPlugin.java
There's no immediate need to replicate the same when developing an internal recipe library for Maven, but you can look through what the conventions add to see if there's anything you would like to copy.